# How to display a multi valued parameter in an SSRS report without using a drop-down list

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on an SSRS report that displays the products sold in a selected country. My supervisor would like to see the results filtered first by continent, then by country, and then a table will be populated by results. Hence, I need to use cascading parameters.

The problem is that I am not allowed to use drop-down list for my multi-valued parameters. Rather, they need to appear in a clickable button-like objects, so the end user clicks on the Asia cell/box, then on the China cell/box, and eventually the results are displayed in the table.
Is it possible to do it this way? and how?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible solution is to create set of reports.  The first report has a list of continent's, which has a link to the next report which has a list of countries.  It has a filter which accepts a parameter from the first (parent) report which is the list of continent's.  The second report then has another link to the final report, which accepts parameters for the first two parent reports.

I have seen this technique demonstrated in a couple of places before.  It is based on drill through reports see [here for more information on drill through reports](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337477(v=sql.105).aspx).  It is not as good as a custom webpage however not everyone has a friendly web developer available :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand that in Reporting Services report design the parameter input controls that allow the user to select parameter values **are not part of the report**. They are a part of the application that the report is hosted in, such as Report Manager or SharePoint.

Report Manager and SharePoint display the available values for parameters as a drop-down list and there is no way to change this that I am aware of. To achieve the design that's been specified you will need to embed a "Report Viewer" control in a bespoke application or web site and design custom parameter controls to pass the selected parameter values to the report.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. My partner is working on a web form to display the report with drop-down list parameters. It looks much better in a web form. In the mean time, I may use a table to display the different values for a Continent, and another table that displays the values of Country for that specific Continent. I hope this works!